# Google doc list api using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-drive-api

how do i view documents on my private cloud using google doc list api on my browser. I am using .net technologies

Comment: What have you tried? What isnt working? Giving answers to these questions will make people more likely to help you as this is a very broad question otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

You should check the Google Drive SDK documentation which includes a complete ASP.NET MVC sample that interacts with files stored on Google Drive:

https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/dotnet